# Salvar foto em MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Estou tentando salvar foto no banco de dados, seguindo este [link](https://medium.com/@fulviocanducci/asp-net-mvc-core-e-entity-framework-core-gravando-fotos-em-uma-tabela-do-banco-de-dados-ad9441248c93), porém não está funcionando.
Aqui é o código HTML:

```
    <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Foto" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Foto" type="file" name="Img" id="Img" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Foto" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
```

A classe que criei:

```
public static class Utils
{
    public static string GetExtension(this IFormFile file)
    {
        return Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
    }
    public static byte[] ToByteArray(this IFormFile file)
    {
        using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(file.OpenReadStream()))
        {
            return reader.ReadBytes((int)file.Length);
        }
    }
}
```

E aqui tento passar assim para o controller:

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> Novo(NovoViewModel model, IFormFile Img)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var produto = new Produto
            {
                nome = model.Nome,
                Foto = Img.ToByteArray()

            };
             db.Add(produto);
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction("Editar", "Produto", new { id });
      }
    }
```

Está me retornando a seguinte messagem:

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

No banco o campo `Foto` foi criado da seguinte forma.

```
public byte[] Foto { get; set; }
```

Ele retorna erro, nesta linha:

```
using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(file.OpenReadStream()))
```

Comment: Em qual linha ele está retornando o erro? É na sua classe de transformação ou no seu controller?

Comment: @VictorLaio editei a pergunta com a linha onde retorna o erro.

Comment: O arquivo chega no método ToByteArray preenchido?

Comment: Não @devgirl ele chega null.